# How to read JSON (in mentioned format)?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, nessus

I have to parse and get the `'id'` field value alone (i.e `13` in this case) from the below JSON response. My JSON response will be in the below format. This is get policies nessus call

```
{'policies': [{'creation_date': 1546583582,
               'description': 'New Scan',
               'has_credentials': 0,
               'id': 13}]}
```

My code:

```
import requests
from first import *
url = 'https://localhost:8834/policies'
headers = {'X-Cookie':mys()}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
resp = response.json()
for k,v in resp.items():
    print (v)
```

Code response:

```
[{'creation_date': 1546583582,'description': 'New Scan','has_credentials': 0,'id': 13}]
```

I'm unsure how to write a code to get the result as expected response - `'id' : 13` or just `13`.

Comment: Say you call the list at the end `a`. Then it would be `a[0][‘id’]`.

Comment: @JackMoody : bro! I get the entire file([{'creation_date': 1546583582,'description': 'New Scan','has_credentials': 0,'id': 13}]) as part of response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False) but I need to know how to print 'id'=13 value alone?

Comment: I think @JackMoody meant, put in terms of your code, to use `print(v[0]['id'])`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it either of these ways:

```
resp = {'policies': [{'creation_date': 1546583582,
                      'description': 'New Scan',
                      'has_credentials': 0,
                      'id': 13}]}

for k,v in resp.items():
    print(v[0]['id'])  # -> 13

# or

print(resp.popitem()[1][0]['id'])  # -> 13
```

Answer (score 0):

In case when you have several policies and want to extract ids to list you can use a list comprehension like 
`[policy.get('id') for policies in resp.values() for policy in policies]` thus you'll get a list of ids

the alternative is loop:

`for policies in resp.values():
    for policy in policies:
        print(policy.get('id'))`